# Game Maker - Directional Velocity

Tags: game-physics, game-maker, gml

I have a game where you are spaceship, the background moves behind you, simulating movement.

The velocity is taken from the player object and then applied to each Asteroid instance, with the players direction.

The issue is that the direction is controlled by the mouse, the creates issues, for example if i'm moving exactly left at a high velocity and then turn around to move exactly right the stop is instant and I instantly move right. This isn't realistic, does anyone have any ideas on how i could implement a more realistic velocity change without removing the mouse control.

Comment: Show your current code. As it stands this is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is what you are looking for but this runs very smoothly: Put this in the player object's step event:

```
direction = point_direction(x, y, mouse_x, mouse_y)
speed = distance_to_point(mouse_x, mouse_y) / 10
```

The smaller the distance to the mouse the slower the player will go.

Answer (score 0):

Use motion_add() to simulate forces acting upon your spaceship, instead of instantly setting your velocity.